# Software to use to route directions on campus maps

Tags: javascript, maps, google-maps

What kind of software would you recommend for a broke college student who's planning on creating a campus map where people can search for directions for their classes? I'm doing this project for a class and I've been looking at google maps api but it seems that they give you a $300 credit limit, and I'm not sure if the credit's enough since I've never used this library and I would be testing the code to see if I'm coding it correctly. Are there any other software that you would recommend that's free and can find routes to buildings? Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Have you looked at http://osmand.net/